# Raw sockets need root priviliege

Tags: security

Why do we need root privileges when we use raw sockets ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you can spoof custom packets, which may interfere with inbound traffic.  This too is also bad.

Comment: -1 for confusing the question. Raw sockets (CAP_NET_RAW) aren't the same as using low ports (CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE). They are related, but spoofing arbitrary packets is a bigger issue, letting you destroy the traffic of everything on the local subnet.

Comment: @NicholasWilson - Fixed, though I'm not sure if this reasoning applies to all Operating Systems.  What OS are you referring to?

Answer (score 4):

In short raw sockets is restricted to root because if it otherwise it would break other rules for networking that are in place.

A long standing rule is that you cannot bind on a port lower than 1024 without root's blessing.  With raw sockets you can simulate a server on any port.  (naturally being able to receive on this port is a different story you'd also have to sniff the network,  but perhaps this could be done with a different machine.)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to write a small sniff program and when I tried to execute the small code I was not able to do it because I didn't login as root

Answer (score 2):

Opening a raw socket allows to read anything that is received in a given interface, so, basically, you can read any packet that is directed to any application - even if that application is owned by another user. That basically means that the user with this capability is able to read any and all communications of all users.