# Why getting IOException when pinging to rechable host using ICMPClient of POCO library?

Tags: ping, poco-libraries

I could not use POCO ping functionality as getting IOException when pinging to reachable host. 
Below is my ping example:

```
#include "Poco/Net/ICMPClient.h"
#include "Poco/Net/IPAddress.h"
#include "Poco/Net/ICMPEventArgs.h"
#include "Poco/Delegate.h"
#include <iostream>


using Poco::Net::ICMPClient;
using Poco::Net::IPAddress;
using Poco::Net::ICMPEventArgs;


class PingExample {
public:
PingExample(): 
    _icmpClient(IPAddress::IPv4)
{
    _icmpClient.pingBegin += Poco::delegate(this, &PingExample::onBegin);
    _icmpClient.pingReply += Poco::delegate(this, &PingExample::onReply);
    _icmpClient.pingError += Poco::delegate(this, &PingExample::onError);
    _icmpClient.pingEnd   += Poco::delegate(this, &PingExample::onEnd);
}


int start_ping(const std::string& host)
{
    _icmpClient.ping(host);
}


void onBegin(const void* pSender, ICMPEventArgs& args)
{
    std::cout << "Pinging " << args.hostName() << " [" << args.hostAddress() << "] with " << args.dataSize() << " bytes of data:" 
       << std::endl << "---------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
}

void onReply(const void* pSender, ICMPEventArgs& args)
{
    std::cout << "Reply from " << args.hostAddress()
       << " bytes=" << args.dataSize() 
       << " time=" << args.replyTime() << "ms"
       << " TTL=" << args.ttl();
}

void onError(const void* pSender, ICMPEventArgs& args)
{
    std::cout << args.error();
}

void onEnd(const void* pSender, ICMPEventArgs& args)
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "--- Ping statistics for " << args.hostName() << " ---"
       << std::endl << "Packets: Sent=" << args.sent() << ", Received=" << args.received()
       << " Lost=" << args.repetitions() - args.received() << " (" << 100.0 - args.percent() << "% loss),"
       << std::endl << "Approximate round trip times in milliseconds: " << std::endl
       << "Minimum=" << args.minRTT() << "ms, Maximum=" << args.maxRTT()  
       << "ms, Average=" << args.avgRTT() << "ms" 
       << std::endl << "------------------------------------------";
}

private:
       ICMPClient  _icmpClient;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    PingExample p;
    p.start_ping("localhost");
    while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

Getting the following exception when running this code:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Poco::IOException'
what():  I/O error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The same exception is getting when

- running Net/samples/Ping/src/Ping.cpp test case without any argument (in this case it should ping to localhost) or when specifying the target as argument
- trying to ping to SocketAddres.
- trying to ping to reachable host not to localhost.

What is the reason of getting IOException exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICMPClient uses raw sockets. That means that you have to run your executable with root permission.
See here: [Raw sockets need root priviliege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404860/raw-sockets-need-root-priviliege)